# How to avoid schema repetitions in MONGODB model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Consider the `document` mentioned below

```
const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    test1: {
        name: String,
        email: String
    },
    test2: {
        name: String,
        email: String
    }
    test3: {
        name: String,
        email: String
    }
    test4: {
        name: String,
        email: String
    }
});
```

In above model `test1, test2, test3...` has repeated data in it. Is there a way to avoid this method ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your schema keeps a list of records you could store them such as

```
const RecordsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {              //
        type: String,    //
        required: true,  //     dummy
        maxLength: 254   //              
    },                   //
    tests: {
        type: [mongoose.Schema.ObjectId],
        ref: 'TestSchema',
        required: false
    }
}

const TestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxLength: 254
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxLength: 254,
        trim: true
    }
}
```

This way you create a model that will define every tests independently, and your controller can then link this Test object to an array located in the RecordsSchema Model